# I have 2 errors when I'm programmig

Tags: c#

I'm making a game and it's my very first one. I got two errors when I'm programming the player movement:

> [01:25:12] Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(3,14): error CS0101: The namespace '' already contains a definition for 'PlayerMovement'

> [01:25:12] Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(11,10): error CS0111: Type 'PlayerMovement' already defines a member called 'FixedUpdate' with the same parameter types

Heres the script:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float forwardForce = 2000f;
    public float sidewaysForce = 500f;
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);
        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
    }
}
```

I have this script from a Youtuber. I followed the instructions from that YouTuber, but it doesn't work.

Comment: One of your problems is that you asked your question incorrectly. On Stackoverflow, your code should be pasted into your question _as text_ (not as a picture), formatted as `code`. Your errors should also be text, and include the error code, the error text, and an indication of where the error orccurred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have created two classes with same name `PlayerMovement`. Either change the class name or delete one class if that is not required.

Comment: thank you very much i tried many hours to solve  ty again

Answer (score -1):

Try to rename your class "PlayerMovement"

Comment: How do I do that?